# Существует ли способ отрисовать прямоугольник в PictureBox, используя кооридинаты указанные из txt?

Tags: c#, winforms

Не могу найти способ нарисовать прямоугольник по координатам в PictureBox, извиняюсь за, возможно глупый вопрос, я всего лишь новичок, а информацию в интернете, к сожалению, найти мне так и не удалось
edit(!):Извиняюсь за возможную неясность, дело в том, я не смог найти именно отрисовку по координатам в формате X Y для каждой вершины, как раз именно это я в интернете не нашел, а может быть не так искал

Comment: Вы приложите ваши попытки хотя бы, в каком направлении уже думали, что совсем не понятно?

Comment: [Вы точно искали?](https://yandex.ru/search/smart/?text=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20picturebox) [Кажется, вы просто не искали.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20picturebox)

Comment: Трудно поверить, что по запросу в гугле "C# draw rectangle" ничего не находит.

Comment: Предоставьте хотя-бы пример данных, которые хранятся в txt